# Deploying New Relic with Octopress blog

Tags: heroku, blogs, newrelic, octopress

I want to try out New Relic on one of my Octopress blogs.  I've followed the quick "wizard" that is provided at the New Relic website:

1. Language: Ruby
2. Generated License Key
3. Added gem 'newrelic_rpm' to my Gemfile and ran bundle install
4. Downloaded the newrelic.yml (I created a config directory in the root of my Octopress blog and placed it in there (config/newrelic.yml)
5. I committed my changes and then deployed to Heroku

I understand that Octopress is a little bit different than a traditional rails app, but I would think that this is all that I need to get new relic up and running.  At this point however, I'm not receiving any data.

Is there anything that I'm missing?  Are their additional settings that I need to do to get New Relic setup on my blog, possibly more configs on the app or Heroku itself?  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Octopress generates static files. NewRelic works on the server side, by running along with the application and inspecting the flow of a request.

It means there is no way to monitor the result of your blog using New Relic and it doesn't even make a lot of sense because there is no server-side processing (apart from service a static file) involved in your case.

Comment: What if you wanted to have it set up so that new relic could ping your site to see if it's up?

Comment: New Relic really needs to run with a ruby app to get started. If you really want to use availability monitoring only, you'll first need to install New Relic on a simple Rails or Sinatra app. It only needs to report once, but you need to do this to get an application to show up in your New Relic dashboard. Once you've done this, you can set up the ping url associated with that application to be anything you want, but you won't be able to collect any web server or end user data.